# Does the put method increases the "modCount" in case of replacing the old value for a given key?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

In the below code (actual implementation of put method inside HashMap), I see the modCount is incremented only in case of new entry getting added but not sure whether it is getting incremented in normal case of replacement of old value and inserting new value for a given key. But I have an understanding that mod count increases in case of the hashmap structure changes, i.e in case of add, remove or update the value inside a map. Can someone explain this, as I do not see here in the code the modCount getting incremented inside the if part rather outside the for loop (so is it only for adding anew value, this modCount changes)?

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
 if (key == null)
     return putForNullKey(value);
  int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
  int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
  for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
       Object k;
       if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
           V oldValue = e.value;
           e.value = value;
           e.recordAccess(this);
           return oldValue;
       }
  }
  modCount++;
  addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
  return null;
}
```

Comment: modcount++ is not inside the if condition, where you see it inside if condition ?

Comment: modCount is increased in any case where this method is called. If the key is null it is increased within the putForNullKey method, if key is not null, it is increased after the for loop is done. I'm not sure I understand your question but just looking at the method, modCount is increased in any case for put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied below directly from the javadoc of modcount of hashmap.java class :-

> /**
>        * The number of times this HashMap has been structurally modified
>        * Structural modifications are those that change the number of mappings in
>        * the HashMap or otherwise modify its internal structure (e.g.,
>        * rehash).  This field is used to make iterators on Collection-views of
>        * the HashMap fail-fast.  (See ConcurrentModificationException).
>        */

So Modcount will not be changed if you replace the old value for a key and i am using java-8 and below is the piece of code which replace the value for a existing key :-

```
if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
                V oldValue = e.value;
                if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
                    e.value = value;
                afterNodeAccess(e);
                return oldValue;
            }
```

And modcount++ is increase after above line but note here we are returning and see the comment **// existing mapping for key**. 
So to answer your question modcount is not increase in case of value is replace for existing key as it will neither change the structure of hashmap nor it will cause the rehashing of map.

Note:- Even the code sample which you have provided there also you can notice that if its for existing key its replacing the value and returning the old value, which is the return for a put method. so line **modCount++;** will not be executed.

Hope i am clear and let me know if you have some doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 [`HashMap` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) literally say (emphasis mine):

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; **merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification**.)

So, as `modCount` keeps the count of structural modifications to the map, the answer to your question is: no, `modCount` is not increased in case of replacing the old value for a given key.